# How to change the word separator character in a vector?

Tags: r

I have a character vector consisting of the following style:

```
mylist <- c('John Myer Stewert','Steve',' Michael Boris',' Daniel and Frieds','Michael-Myer')
```

I'm trying to create a character vector like this:

```
mylist <- c('John+Myer+Stewert','Steve',' Michael+Boris',' Daniel+and+Frieds','Michael+Myer')
```

I have tried:

```
test <- cat(paste(shQuote(mylist , type="cmd"), collapse="+"))
```

That seems wrong.  How can I change the word separator in `mylist` as shown above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `gsub` by matching the space (`" "`) as pattern and replace it with `"+"`.

```
gsub(" ", "+", trimws(mylist))
#[1] "John+Myer+Stewert" "Steve"             "Michael+Boris"   
#[4]  "Daniel+and+Frieds" "Michael-Myer"
```

I assumed that the leading spaces as typo.  If it is not, we can either use regex lookarounds

```
gsub("(?<=[a-z])[ -](?=[[:alpha:]])", "+", mylist, perl = TRUE)
#[1] "John+Myer+Stewert"  "Steve"              " Michael+Boris"    
#[4] " Daniel+and+Frieds" "Michael+Myer"
```

Or some PCRE regex

```
gsub("(^ | $)(*SKIP)(*F)|[ -]", "+", mylist, perl = TRUE)
#[1] "John+Myer+Stewert"  "Steve"              " Michael+Boris"    
#[4] " Daniel+and+Frieds" "Michael+Myer"
```

Comment: thank you for posting that. Im very sorry. I forgot one example, which I added to the list

Comment: @HiThere No problem.  The answer is updated as well.

Comment: @ akrun that great. Thx!

Comment: @akrun, based on the OP's question, you also need to replace the dash between Michael and Boris by a plus sign. For example by specifying "[ -]" in gsub instead of " ".

Comment: @milan The OP changed his input and output many times.  Thanks.  It is fixed

Answer (score 6):

You could use `chartr()`.  Just re-use the `+` sign for both space and `-` characters.

```
chartr(" -", "++", trimws(mylist))
# [1] "John+Myer+Stewert" "Steve"             "Michael+Boris"    
# [4] "Daniel+and+Frieds" "Michael+Myer"
```

Note that I also trimmed the leading whitespace since there is really no need to keep it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the package `stringr`.

```
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(trimws(mylist), "[ -]", "+")
#[1] "John+Myer+Stewert" "Steve" "Michael+Boris"
#[4] "Daniel+and+Frieds" "Michael+Myer"
```

Between `[]` we specify what we want to replace with `+`. In this case, that is a single white space and `-`. I used `trimws` from Akrun's answer to get rid of the extra white space in the beginning of some elements in your string.

This is yet another alternative.

```
library(stringi)
stri_replace_all_regex(trimws(mylist), "[ -]", "+")
```